# JavaScript - variable incremented in for loop issue

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I was trying to make a for loop that increments through the numbers 1 - 4 and print them, but when I printed the value of i after the loop, my code outputs 5.

```js
for (i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  document.write(i + "<br>"); //Outputs numbers 1 - 4
}

document.write("New i: " + i); //Outputs 5
```

How is this possible if i can only increment up until its value is 4?

Comment: That's why the loop stops, because basically the `i` has `5` value and since you have made the `i` variable global, you can access it outside the `for` loop and it holds `5` value.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_()

Comment: `i++` happens at the END of every iteration, so when `i` is equal to 4 you write it to the document and then `i` gets incremented to 5 - that's what causes `i < 5` to be false and have the loop stop, `i` is now `5`.

Comment: Why don't you just set a variable to 5?

Answer (score 1):

You could move the *final-expression* part into the *condition* part of the [`for` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for), where the increment takes place only if the value is smaller than `4`.

```js
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 4 && ++i;) {
    console.log(i);            // 1 ... 4
}

console.log('last value', i);  // 4
```

Answer (score 1):

When you declare a variable in a loop statement, it stores the variable in the same scope as the loop. Loops increment (i++) at the end of the loop, then check the condition (i < 5) to see if they should repeat. After the loop, the variable i still exists. See the snippet below for a play-by play.

Also, you should use the var keyword when declaring i, otherwise, the variable is stored in the global scope (which is bad practice).

```js
//variable i is captured here (with the var keyword)

for(var i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
  //for the fourth iteration, i === 4
  
  //so it prints 4.
  document.write(i);
  
  
  //i++ happens right now, so i now is 5.
  //then the loop checks the condition to see if it
  //should continue. i isn't less than 5, so the loop breaks.
}

//and the value of i is still 5. so this prints 5.
document.write('</br>' + i);
```

Answer (score 0):

The test clause of i < 5 is evaluated at the beginning of each loop; if it is false, the loop exits (leaving the value at 5).  The i++ part always happens at the end of an iteration, meaning that after the number 4 has been processed in the loop, it increments it to 5, then it loops to the top of the loop where it checks the condition again (i<5) which it fails, but the value of i is not reversed back to 4.

Answer (score -1):

- The condition of the loop block to be processed is `i < 5`, thus `i` must be less than 5 for the statements and expressions within it to be evaluated
- You increment `i` by 1 with each pass
- When `i` equals 4, you increment it by 1 again such that `i` will be equal to 5.  `i < 5` is no longer true, so within the loop block is not executed
- Nothing turns `i` back one increment; so it retains it after the loop

You can apply unique ways, but generally the first and last example below is the common approach:

```js
var log = console.log;

// Example 1: Decrease Loop Iterator After
for (var i = 1; i < 5; i++)
  log(i);
log('New i:', --i); // 4


// Example 2:  Count in conditional
var count = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < 5 && ++count; i++)
  log(i);
log('New i:', count); // 4


// Example 3: Count in loop body
var count = 0;
for (var i = 1; i < 5 && ++count; i++)
  log(i);
log('New i:', count); // 4
```

Answer (score -1):

1. you have declared i as global variable.
2. That's how the for loop works.

```js
 for (initialization, condition, increment/decrement ) {
    
    }
```

You have initialized with 1 and it satisfies the condition i<5 so it enters the loop and prints i. after then it performs the increment/decrement operation and increases the value by 1 in your case. So while i=4 and i<5 it enters the loop and prints 4, but after then it performs increment operation and increase the value of i to 5.

In the next step, as the condition i<5 is not satisfied , so it breaks the loop and go to the last statement, where you are printing i, that is 5.

Hope it is clear now.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
array.forEach(function(value) {
  document.write(value + "<br />");
});
document.write("Values processed: " + array.length);
```

No, I‘m not kidding. Use arrays whenever you can, they will spare you a lot of trouble. The side effect you‘re in fact asking for can cause hard-to-track bugs (`i` looks like being meant for the loop only, imagine tons of lines between the loop and the last `document.write`). And there‘s the [off-by-one error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error) problem with `for` loops.

You‘ll probably anyway end up with an array once your code starts doing meaningful stuff (you don‘t want to count up to 4, do you?). So do yourself a favor an embrace all those powerful [Array methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array).

Answer (score -2):

please use count variable because i value increases after each statement execution. i.e after your loop is finished execution i will be always 5

```js
var count=0;
for (i = 1; i <5; i++) {
  document.write(i + "<br>"); //I increases after these statement execution so it will be 5 at last
  count=count+1;
}

document.write("New i: " + count); //Outputs 5
```